# Celery can't launch tasks by schedule despite settings

Tags: django, docker, celery

I have a django project with this code:

settings.py

```
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = False
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Omsk'
```

celery.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
 
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
 
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'sendings.settings')
 
app = Celery('sendings')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
 
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'sending_to_emails': {
        'task': 'app.tasks.sendings',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=36, hour=22)
    },
}
```

In my docker-container based on alpine image i check datetime and it's correct accordings with my tz settings.

I down my docker containers and rebuild them, but this problem still remains.

Comment: Please share you docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run two processes `celery beat` for scheduling tasks and `celery worker` for consuming and processing tasks. To check whether `app.tasks.sendings` task is registered and beat is sending messages as expected, run the worker and beat scheduler in `DEBUG` mode as follows.

```
celery -A celery worker --loglevel DEBUG
celery -A celery beat --loglevel DEBUG
```

As you are using docker, you can either start a background job in your container or use a separate container to accomplish the same or run beat without docker.

Comment: Hello, Lemon! I fix it by set version of celery[redis]=4.2.0 in requirements.txt. So i did  upgraded celery.